# How to show pop up before adding an item to list in Vue.Draggable?

Tags: javascript, vuedraggable

I am dragging an item from a list to another list to add or drop.

I want to open a pop up before adding the dragged item to list.

I have used the @drop event to do, but the drop event is triggered only after the dragged item is dropped into the list.

How to show my pop up before dropping an item to the list using Vue.Draggable?

Comment: Hi, did you figure this out?

Comment: yes @aznmik I figured this out. I will share the github link

Comment: It would be great if you could share the solution :)

Comment: @aznmik please refer this link `https://github.com/cameronhimself/vue-drag-drop` & `https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable`. You have to add the drop event listener to your component.
1. Create your drag-drop lists. Drag an item from the list to another drop list and drop on the list.
2. Add drop event listener to the div item or where you want. 
3. Have a popup with Accept, Reject after dropping an item on drop div, if Reject is clicked do not add the dragged item to drop list.